# Flutter I am trying to build app but I am facing this issue

Tags: flutter, dart

The error seems to be of dat:html but I am not developing for either web or desktop. I am not able to fix this issue please help

I dont remember what I have done before the error occured

/C:/Users/Parvez/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/universal_html-2.2.2/lib/src/html/dom/element_subclasses.dart:2752:30: Error: The argument type 'String?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Object' because 'String?' is nullable and 'Object' isn't.

- 'Object' is from 'dart:core'.
  final parsed = css.parse(text);
  ^
  Target kernel_snapshot failed: Exception

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Script 'D:\src\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\flutter.gradle' line: 1151

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.
> Process 'command 'D:\src\flutter\bin\flutter.bat'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

And here is my pubspec.yaml

name: canverro
description: A new Flutter project.

version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
sdk: '>=2.12.0 <3.0.0'

dependencies:
flutter:
sdk: flutter
cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
flutter_staggered_grid_view: ^0.6.2
google_fonts: ^4.0.1
carousel_slider: ^4.1.1
smooth_page_indicator: ^1.0.0+2
flutter_svg: ^2.0.5
firebase_core: ^2.4.1
permission_handler: ^10.0.0
http: ^0.13.5
flutter_custom_clippers: ^2.0.0
email_validator: ^2.0.1
rflutter_alert: ^2.0.4
image_cropper: ^3.0.1
gradient_borders: ^1.0.0
screenshot: ^1.3.0
image_picker: ^0.8.7
flutter_colorpicker: ^1.0.3
matrix_gesture_detector: ^0.2.0-nullsafety.1
readmore: ^2.2.0
firebase_database: ^10.2.1
charts_painter: ^3.1.1
#Google_Sign_In
firebase_auth: ^4.2.2

#State_Management
provider: ^6.0.3

#Cookie
sweet_cookie: ^0.0.5
shared_preferences: ^2.1.0
sweet_cookie_jar: ^1.1.0

community_material_icon: ^5.9.55
flutter_rating_bar: ^4.0.1

#Payment

dev_dependencies:
flutter_test:
sdk: flutter
json_serializable: ^6.6.1
flutter_lints: ^2.0.0

flutter:
assets:
- images/

I tried upgrading and downgrading the flutter and dart.
I also tried flutter clean but still the error pursued

Comment: remove the line with import 'package:flutter/html' or similar.

Comment: check if have you imported dart:html anywhere in your project.
remove it if is there.

Comment: No there is no imported dart:html or flutter/html in the project

Comment: Can you provide the piece of code causing the error ? Did you already solve ?

Answer (score 8):

I found the answer in [Here](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/92792)

You just need to add `csslib: 0.17.0` in your project.

Comment: I am SOOOOO confused, somehow this worked but the link doesn't link to any related issue

Comment: This works, but not on csslib: 0.17.3 and above. I know the answer must be in the margins of that page somewhere @Nzri but can you tell us how the above solution solves the Null safety issue in universal_html?

Comment: Holding back the `csslib` version that `universal_html` had an issue with will also hold back other packages from using a newer version of `csslib`. 

If instead you update `universal_html` to a version that is compatible with later versions of `csslib`, you will no longer be stuck on old versions of everything

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to find the exact cause: remove pubspec.lock and then restart the IDE OR issue related to flutter version 3.X.X

Comment: it didnt worked

Answer (score 0):

This issue was tracked [here](https://github.com/dint-dev/universal_html/issues/76). They fixed the issue in `universal_html` version 2.2.3.

##### Case 1:

If your project depends on `universal_html` directly already, you can update `pubspec.yaml` like this:

```
dependencies:
  universal_html: ^2.2.3
```

##### Case 2:

If your project doesn't depend on `universal_html` directly (only a transitive dependency), you can look the package that depends on it (`pub deps` is a useful tool to find such packages). If that package has an update that now has it depending on `universal_html: >2.2.3`, you can update your pubspec.yaml in a similar way to the above, for that package. Or if you don't want to update the other packages, you can do a dependency override for your project:

```
dependency_overrides:
  universal_html: ^2.2.3
```

Either option for Case 2 has potential issues - upgrading the package that depends on `universal_html` could bring more breaking changes (but technically it shouldn't if it isn't a major version upgrade) -- or doing a dependency override could cause issues next time you go to update packages, when some other dependency or your package conflicts with your override rule.